# Как сделать запись сразу в два столбца?

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Как сделать запись в БД в две колонки?
Есть два списка:

```
title = [['Приехали гости'], ['Уехали гости']]
img = [['url=1'], ['url=2']]
```

Надо чтобы в БД была на выходе вот такая запись:

[image: БД]

Вот код для записи одной колонки `title`:

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
c = conn.cursor()

title = [['Приехали гости'], ['Уехали гости']]
img = [['url=1'], ['url=2']]

def add_db():
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO Article(title) VALUES (?)", (title))

add_db()

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
title = ['Приехали гости', 'Уехали гости']
img = ['url=1', 'url=2']

records = [x for x in zip(title, img)]

c.executemany("INSERT INTO Article(title, img) VALUES (?, ?)", records)
```

Метод `cursor.executemany(query, records)` ожидает в качестве `records` - коллекцию значений. В вашем случае эта коллекция должна выглядеть как список кортежей:

```
In [33]: records
Out[33]: [('Приехали гости', 'url=1'), ('Уехали гости', 'url=2')]
```

или как список списков:

```
In [33]: records
Out[33]: [['Приехали гости', 'url=1'], ['Уехали гости', 'url=2']]
```

Comment: почему `[x for x in zip(title, img)]` а не `list(zip(title, img))`?

Comment: @Danis, можно и так, конечно